# Shiny : Update Select Input based on Radio button Choice

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app , which has two classes . Class A with categories a1,b1... , Class B with categories a2,b2 ...

I have a radio buttons with "Class A" and "Class B"  and based on choices , I would like to update my user Input :

```
library(collapsibleTree)
library(shiny)
library(Cairo)
library(rsconnect)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("dsfs", align="center")),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(


#update selectInput based on it :
radioButtons(inputId = "buttons", "Selections", c("class A", "Class 
B"), 
selected = "Class A", inline = TRUE),


selectInput( "selection","Select a  Category ",choices = 
"",selected="")


),mainPanel(



diagonalNetworkOutput ("collapsiblenetwork")
)

))
)
```

**server.r**

```
    shinyServer(
    function(session,input,output){

output$collapsiblenetwork<-renderDiagonalNetwork({

if(input$buttons=="Class A"){
observeEvent( 
input$selection,updateSelectInput(session,"selection","Select a 
category ",choices = levels(class A$categories))
    )


user_input_value_superclass<-input$selection
    print(user_input_value_superclass)

# detection rate function :produces a  dataframe 
    classA_detect<- 
detecttion_rates(user_input_class_subclass_superclass = 
user_input_value_superclass,user_input_shiny_header ="Class A" )
    ClassA_superclass<-as.Node(ClassA_detect)    

    useRtreeList <- ToListExplicit(ClassA_superclass, unname = TRUE)
    network_plot<-diagonalNetwork( useRtreeList)


  }else if(input$buttons=="Class B") {


    observeEvent( 
   input$selection,updateSelectInput(session,"selection","Select a 
   category ",choices = levels(classB$categories))
    )

    user_input_value_subclass<-input$selection
   ClassB_detect<-detecttion_rates(user_input_class_subclass_superclass 
    = user_input_value_subclass,user_input_shiny_header = "Class B")

    ClassB_subclass<-as.Node(ClassB_detect)    

    useRtreeList <- ToListExplicit(ClassB_subclass, unname = TRUE)
    diagonalNetwork( useRtreeList)



  }   


})


})
```

The code Produces , the radio buttons and the selection inputs accordingly , but as soon as I select a input other than the default input value ,for that class , the plot  for the new selection is plotted for a split second automatically renders back  to the original plot (i.e default selection).
Everything else works fine .
I tried printing the input after updating the select input , it produces an empty string "". 
Apologies for the long script.
Thanks!

Comment: I really hate to put it this way, but your code needs a lot of re-do. I have a tough time understanding what you're even trying to do. Some general recommendations: 1. Create reactive objects such as `obj <- reactive(...)` into small chunks, and then pass that into your `render*()` call. Don't make a massive render and use `observeEvent()` within it. 2. Use `#` to make a comment. 3. If `class A` & `class B` are vectors (as I'm assuming by your `levels()` call), they cannot have spaces. 4. There's no reason for `selectInput()` in the UI script, & text to display must be in quotes.

Comment: Totally agree to what @Phil commented; I'd also add that R is case sensitive, so that you can't make reference to one variable in different ways such as classA, ClassA, etc.
Additionally, one important recommendation is to indent your code so that would help you to trace the code, understand syntax errors (e.g. in the titlePanel).